# Spring Security still blocks to endpoints despite the user being authenticated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security with Angular. I want to do stateless authentication with JWT tokens and after authenticating the user and setting the SecurityContextHolder, I am trying to access an endpoint * http://localhost:8080/generate/magic*, but I get a 403 error

This is my securityFilterChain

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(customizer -> customizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
```

And my WebConfig class for CORS if it's relevant

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig {

    private static final Long MAX_AGE = 3600L;
    private static final int CORS_FILTER_ORDER = -102;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
                HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                HttpHeaders.ACCEPT));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                HttpMethod.DELETE.name()));
        config.setMaxAge(MAX_AGE);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));

        // should be set order to -100 because we need to CorsFilter before SpringSecurityFilter
        bean.setOrder(CORS_FILTER_ORDER);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The error goes away if I explicitly add `.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/generate/magic").permitAll()` In my securityFilterChain. Shouldnt the line `.anyRequest().authenticated()`make sure that if the user is authenticated they should be allowed to access all other endpoints? I checked on my server side and the user is still authenticated in Spring Security when making that endpoint call. I would really appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: You are doing stateless authentication, so unless you are sending the usernama/passwords for each request (like basic authentication) you aren't authenticated anymore as there is no state.